# Write a line with ampersand using batch command in a text file

Tags: batch-file, command

I want to write a line in a text file using the batch file.

```
CONTENT=IBFS1_action=createUser&IBFS_name=user2&IBFS_description=user2&IBFS_password=&IBFS_email=&IBFS_status=ACTIVE&IBFS_initGroup=IBFS%3A%2FSSYS%2FGROUPS%2FEVERYONE&IBFS_pSetList=&IBIWF_SES_AUTH_TOKEN=ce15d73b58214ce31c2d1ce96c8f5843&
```

I want to write this line into text file using the batch command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix each `&` with `^`.

Similarly, you need to prefix each `%` with `%`

Comment: Worked as it should ! Thanks a lot